# how to fix error:"The specified type member is not supported in LINQ to Entities ..." on not mapped columns

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, left-join

Table 1:

```
class TRD
{
    [Column("ID")]
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int ID { set; get; }

    [Column("Name", TypeName = "nvarchar")]
    public string Name { set; get; }    // <-- Mapped 

    [Column("LastName", TypeName = "nvarchar")]
    public string LastName { set; get; }    // <-- Mapped 

    public string DisplayFullName    // <-- Not Mapped
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} - {1}", Name, LastName);
        }
    } 
    [Column("gate_id", TypeName = "int")]
    public int gate_id { get; set; }   // <-- Mapped - foreign key
}
```

Table 2:

```
class Gate
{
    [Column("ID")]
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int ID { set; get; } 
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to have TRD left join Gate:

```
var search = OdataBaseContex.TRD.GroupJoin(
        OdataBaseContex.Gates,
        f => f.gate_id,
        p => p.ID,
        (x, y) => new { TRD = x, gate = y })
.SelectMany(
        x => x.gate.DefaultIfEmpty(),
        (x, y) => new {
            LastName = x.TRD.LastName,
            Name = x.TRD.Name,
            DisplayFullName = x.TRD.DisplayFullName,  //<-- Error 
            gate_id = y.name
        }).ToList();
```

Error:

> The specified type member 'DisplayFullName' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: you used `string.Format` and its not supported by Linq and that why it thows an exception instead of this you can use like => `get
        {
            return  Name + "-" + LastName;
        }`

Comment: changed. problem still exist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var search = OdataBaseContex.TRD.GroupJoin(
        OdataBaseContex.Gates,
        f => f.gate_id,
        p => p.ID,
        (x, y) => new { TRD = x, gate = y })
.SelectMany(
        x => x.gate.DefaultIfEmpty(),
        (x, y) => new {
            LastName = x.TRD.LastName,
            Name = x.TRD.Name,
            DisplayFullName = x.TRD.Name+"-"+x.TRD.LastName,   
            gate_id = y.name
        }).ToList();
```

or make that property don't use `string.Format` like `x.TRD.Name+"-"+x.TRD.LastName` :

```
public string DisplayFullName
{
    get
    {
        return Name + " - " + LastName;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
as my comment below, when you want use a method in `Linq-To-Entities` query it makes the transition of query to be executable query for database, so when you call your method in C# going to get translated into some SQL query, so if all C# actually get executed as SQL, there is no problem otherwise you can't call `method()` in main block of query, BTW the workaround and easy solution is to split that query to separate parts like below:

```
var search = OdataBaseContex.TRD.GroupJoin(
        OdataBaseContex.Gates,
        f => f.gate_id,
        p => p.ID,
        (x, y) => new { TRD = x, gate = y })
.SelectMany(
        x => x.gate.DefaultIfEmpty(),
        (x, y) => new
        {
            LastName = x.TRD.LastName,
            Name = x.TRD.Name, 
            gate_id = y.name
        }).ToList().Select(mn => new
        {
            LastName = mn.LastName,
            Name = mn.Name,
            DisplayFullName = GetFullName(mn.Name,mn.LastName)
            gate_id = mn.gate_id
        });
```

by calling `ToList()` you query will execute on DB and then by the last `Select()` you will get something you want.
Or suppose you have a `DTO` class like below :

```
public class DtoClass
{ 
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public int GateId { get; set; }
    public string ShamsiDate { get; set; }
}
```

then you can run your query in two steps:

```
var search = OdataBaseContex.TRD.GroupJoin(
        OdataBaseContex.Gates,
        f => f.gate_id,
        p => p.ID,
        (x, y) => new { TRD = x, gate = y })
.SelectMany(
        x => x.gate.DefaultIfEmpty(),
        (x, y) => new
        {
            LastName = x.TRD.LastName,
            Name = x.TRD.Name,
            gate_id = y.name
        }).ToList();//query will be executed on DB because of ToList()
List<DtoClass> results = search.Select(mn =>
        {
            //Manipulating mn data 
            //call some custom method to cast Date
            string newDate = CastMiladi2Other(date);
            DtoClass ret = new DtoClass()
            { 
                FullName = GetFullName(mn.Name, mn.LastName),
                ShamsiDate = newDate,
                GateId = mn.gate_id
            };
            return ret;
        }).ToList();
```

in `Select()` of `results` you can do and call any methods you want, you can also use `AsEnumerable()` instead of `ToList()` , the rest of the query will then be evaluated as an in memory collection using `Linq-to-Objects`.

Comment: thank's for answer. it work. but this is a simple sample! major problem is when i have computed columns or want convert miladi date to other!

Comment: You are welcome, I know you may want to convert Miladi date to another format like Shamsi or Persian date, for that calling method split query into two statements, firstly execute the query and then iterate it with calling your method like `.SelectMany(..).ToList().Select(x=> CastMiladi(x.Date))`.

Comment: could you explain on this code? (use DisplayFullName  instead DisplayFullName = x.TRD.Name+"-"+x.TRD.LastName)

Comment: See the update and take a look at the comments in code.

Answer (score 0):

Your query wont work as this query is getting converted to SQL query and that time it is not understanding what you have used in setter in .Net class. So, try using expressions instead else the other work around are already listed above i guess which will work for you.